# Add new country in default country dropdown in Magento 2.3.5

Tags: php, magento2.3.5

I need to add new country and its regions/states in Magento 2.3.5
I have already done this for Magento1. There are many references available and provide common solution like add entry in directory_country table and changes in vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml file.
reference: https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/How-to-add-new-country-on-Magento-2-1-1/m-p/69286/highlight/true#M2943
But solutions does not work with Magento 2.3.5

Regards

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [this](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Adding-New-Country/td-p/108520) link.

**Step1:** Open vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\en.xml

**Step2:** Locate territories tag in this file

**Step3:** copy one of territory tags for the syntax and paste it within the territories tag

**Step4:** hard part here is to add country code in this file as might not be able to find a unique one, so it’s upto you.

**Step5:** Save this file

**Step6:** Open table name directory_country

**Step7:** It has predefined syntax follow then same and create a new row and enter the same country code as entered in the en.xml file in 3 columns

**Step8:** Refresh the site’s cache.

**Step9:** Admin > Configuration > General

Hope it will work for you.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already tried this, and its not working. I am using Magento 2.3.5

Comment: Ok if any other clue I will find then will post here. @jemstone

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below link and it helps me to add a new country

[Add new nation into nation's list in Magento 2.3.5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330838/add-new-nation-into-nations-list-in-magento-2-3-5/330897#330897)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link for the step by step solution :

https://praveenchelumalla.com/2022/11/21/how-to-add-a-new-country-in-magento-2-adobe-commerce/

Thank you